# Passing Double From MS Access to Stored Procedure Rounds

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ms-access-2007

I have a stored procedure that is passed one variable when called from MS Access. The passed variable is an exchange rate and varies between 0.8 and 0.999. When I run the sproc through SSMS everything is correct but if I call from MS Access the FxRate inserted in the table is rounded to 1.

Stored proc (stripped down a little) is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateSKNDetailMaster] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Fx decimal(4,3),
    @Ret int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblFxRate (TRUWeek,FxRate)
    VALUES (201412,@Fx)

END
```

Function to call is (again stripped down)

```
Function RefreshSKNDetailMaster(dblFx As Double) As Long

[Connections, sproc anme etc...]

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@Fx", dbDecimal, adParamInput, , dblFx)
param.NumericScale = 3
param.Precision = 4
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@Ret", 20, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append param

CurrentDb.QueryTimeout = 0
cmd.Execute

RefreshSKNDetailMaster = cmd.Parameters("@Ret")

End Function
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFxRate](
    [TruWeek] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FxRate] [decimal](4, 3) NOT NULL,
    [UID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

This approach seems to work fine for similar sprocs but I can't get it to work for this one. I hope I'm not missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong constant to create your first parameter (`@Fx`). You create it as `dbDecimal`, and `dbDecimal` has a value of 20. You want to use `adDecimal`, which has a value of 14. (To an ADODB.Parameter, `dbDecimal = 20 = adBigInt`, which explains why your parameter values were being rounded or truncated to integers.)